# How do I search the name on a IRC message?

Tags: python

I'm doing an IRC bot, and when I run it, it shows a message like the following:

```
:alex!Archive@archive-BFE006B5.red-88-11-62.dynamicip.rima-tde.net PRIVMSG #Bank ::D
```

How do I get the specific name in case (alex)?

Comment: Be more specific about the format of your string and about the characters a username can contain. Is the name always enclosed between the first `:` and first `!`. If yes, the answer is easy.

Comment: Yep, it is. It says: :<user>!

Comment: what if `!` appears in their name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the username is always in between the starting `:` character and the first `!` character, slice your string like this:

```
>>> s = ':alex!Archive@archive-BFE006B5.red-88-11-62.dynamicip.rima-tde.net PRIVMSG #Bank ::D'
>>> s[1:s.index('!')]
'alex'
```

Note that `string.index` will raise a `ValueError` if the substring you are looking for is not found while `string.find` will return `-1`.

Comment: @IronFist That would certainly be the appropriate solution if the strings could have a more general format, but as it stands (check the comments in the question) I understand that the strings are guaranteed to start with `:name!`. If that's not the case, I ask @Alex82 to clarify and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: It always starts with :<name>! .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the name will always be found between the characters `:` and `!`, you can perform a simple `search` using regular expressions:

```
import re

msg= ":alex!Archive@archive-BFE006B5.red-88-11-62.dynamicip.rima-tde.net PRIVMSG #Bank ::D"
result = re.search(r":\w+!", msg)   # searches for any name between a ! and a :

if result:
    print(result.group())   # prints out ":alex!"
    print(result.group()[1:-1])   # prints out "alex"
else:
    print("no name found!")
```

Comment: You could use `regex` more effectively than this and you would save the trouble on yourself indexing on the `group()`...